# EPSON Feeder Scanner driver L5190 Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: drivers, scanner

any suggestion for EPSON feeder Scanner driver L5190 Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

You can find drivers at [Epson drivers download](https://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule) site.